# Is it possible to exit a C# code-behind block with a command?

Tags: c#, code-behind

To simplify this issue, I'm trying to do something like this (aircode):

```
Open a connection
Fill a dataset

If (data field == "")
{
  message "This data field is empty"
  Exit the code
}

Do a **lot** more stuff
```

Can I exit the code at the point indicated above?  If so, what is the proper command?

Comment: C# code behind "script"... what?

Comment: Code behind script.  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=398883&seqNum=2

Comment: I'm sorry that article is wrong. C# is not a scripting language, the code behind is not a "script"

Comment: Is the title more acceptable now?

Comment: you can use "return" to exit the method

Answer (score 2):

```
Open a connection
Fill a dataset

If (data field == "")
{
  message "This data field is empty"
  return;
 }

Do a **lot** more stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to exit the code (i.e. quit the application), you can use [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Environment.Exit(x)
```

... where `x` is the "exit code" that will be returned; in my experience, this is normally for use in Console-based applications. However, this won't clean up anything, and can leave all sorts of stuff that you really should tidy up before exiting... probably not best practice except in extreme cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `return` command. Before exit from the code I recommend to you to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, you can just `return`.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you'd better throw an exception, because your method may be a void type and on the other hand you wanna exit the code when an error occurs so:

```
Open a connection
Fill a dataset

If (data field == "")
{
     throw new Exception("Message");         
}

Do a **lot** more stuff
```